# PhoneGap/Cordova build .apk

Tags: cordova

Just having a little issue with Cordova and need your help as Im pretty new to it!

Only for the purpose of getting familiar with Cordova, I just wanted to be able to create an .apk file and run in on the tablet without goin through the mobile web browser.
So there are no plugins for API etc etc.

So I have created a new Cordova Project on Windows using the Command Prompt.
Added the Android platform.
Put two webpages with their assets(sheet,scripts,img etc) into the www folder.
On the command Prompt, can run it without any problem in the emulator (cordova emulate android), everything works fine (except its dead slow but that's normal in the emulator obviously), panels are moving etc

But when it comes to build the .apk file (cordova build --release), it gives me in the android/ant-build folder a file called "###-release-unasigned.apk".
So far so good but the issue is when you put it in the device (Nexus 7 first gen, running 4.2.2...same as the emulator) it simply cant install it!!

Is there anything I have missed? Some settings to do?
I couldn't find anything from my researches on the Web but clearly something is going wrong.

Thx!!

Comment: Have you allowed installation of apps from unknown sources on your device? I've never tried to install the unsigned release app, I either installed the -debug app or signed the -release app before using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you export your android project and create a keystore to complete the export process.

[image]

[image]